# Using sbt with custom Scala builds

Tags: scala, sbt

I occasionally play with Scala forks and sometimes need to debug these forks on SBT projects. In general, `scalaHome` works great, but there are a few things that I'd like to find better ways to achieve.

1) Is it possible to have SBT pick up custom scalac class files produced by the `ant quick` build rather than jar files emitted by the `ant pack` build? The latter implies 5-10 seconds of additional delay per build, so it'd be great to avoid it.

2) Even in big projects, problems exhibited by scalac usually manifest themselves when compiling single files. Is there a way to tell sbt to neglect its change tracking heuristics and recompile just a single file? What I would particularly like to prevent is recompilation of the whole world when I recompile `scalaHome` or change scalac flags.

3) Would it be possible to have sbt hot reload scalac classes coming from `scalaHome`, when `scalaHome` gets recompiled? Currently I have to shutdown and restart sbt to apply the changes.

Comment: can you provide a sample sbt build file showing off the problem(s) ? As far as I know, `quick` is not a standard sbt command  so you probably have a plugin in there, it would help to know which one ...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant the `quick` ant task from the `scalac` build which produces classfiles that constitute the compiler, as opposed to the `pack` task that packs those classfiles into `scala-compiler.jar`. I updated the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 3):

1) No, this would make sbt depend on the details of the Scala build.  If Scala were built with sbt, you might be able to depend on Scala as a source dependency or at least this could probably be supported without too many changes.

2) No, see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/604

3) sbt 0.13 should check the last modified times of the jars coming from `scalaHome` and use a new class loader.  It is a bug if it does not.